# Is there any benefit of keeping the default boot drive of Windows 10 as C:?

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootable-media, wmi, wmic

I am using below query to find that the default drive in Windows 10 is C:, is there any benefit of keeping it as it is. Also how to change the default boot drive so that it is reflected in the result of this query.

WMI query:

```
SELECT BootDirectory FROM Win32_BootConfiguration WHERE Name='BootConfiguration'
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of changing it?

Comment: The benefit is that people and software won't get confused. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: As far as I remember the partition Windows 10 boots from is always mounted as C:\ you can't change that.

Comment: @Robert: It's possible to semi-accidentally end up with the actual Windows files on a different partition, e.g. my Windows XP desktop was entirely on D: (with only NTLDR still being in C:).

Comment: @user1686 As far as I remember the "Windows drive is always C:\" was introduced with Windows 7, therefore on XP this might be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of keeping it as it is, is that you won't break anything ...

You can change the *default system partition*'s letter, if that's what you meant. You can find microsoft instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/restore-system-boot-drive-letter) (it's done via `regedit`). Be prepared to reinstall windows if anything goes wrong.

P.S. Anything that uses `%SystemRoot%` inside the path, should keep working. Anything that uses `C:\Windows`, will not work anymore.